# Converting to NSDate from NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsstring, nsdate

I am trying to convert a Nsstring object to Nsdate.My code is like this

```
     NSString *Time=@"09/26/2011 2:06 AM";
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        //[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
        //Time=[mystr substringToIndex:3];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM"];
        NSDate *dateFrom = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Time];
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n\nThe date==%@\n\n\n\n\n",dateFrom);
```

But It returns a null value..Any help is Appreciated .Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you even looked at the NSDateFormatter documentation : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM"];
```

with

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"];
```

Comment: Working now..Thanks..Is it possible to  Convert it as 12 hours time .